# How can I manually enter a value in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to enter a date of birth value on a dataset of senators. I rarely touch for loops so I may be doing this wrong but this is what I have so far:

```
    ID <- c("A000055","B001303","M001201")
    D.O.B. <- c("1965-07-22",NA,"1951-11-07")
    leg_complete <- data.frame("name","D.O.B.")

for(id in leg_complete)
  if(ID=="M001201") {
    D.O.B. <- "1956-11-14"
  } else {
    break
  }
```

Whenever I run the code and open the dataset, I get "No data available in the table. Is the for loop even the best move for entering a single value or should I use a different function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. You already have a good start, with the code you tried, including code to make an example dataset. However, you could improve your question by [edit]ing it to include the desired output for your example data. At least for me, how your question's worded now, it's hard for me to envision the output you want to have from this.

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly you're looking for, but you can change specific values using, e.g., ``leg_complete[leg_complete$ID == "M001201", "D.O.B"] <- "1956-11-14"``

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, @fdob!

I think you have a couple of issues in the code you posted above.

First, I think you meant to use `ID` instead of `name` in constructing your dataframe?

Second, you don't need the quotes around each variable either?

So I think you were trying to do this instead?

```
leg_complete <- data.frame(ID,D.O.B.)
```

If that is a correct assumption, then if you wanted to reassign a value in the dataframe, you can do something as simple as the below

```
leg_complete2[ID=="M001201"] <- "1956-11-14"
```

which gives the following:

```
> str(leg_complete)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ID    : Factor w/ 3 levels "A000055","B001303",..: 1 2 3
 $ D.O.B.: Factor w/ 2 levels "1951-11-07","1965-07-22": 2 NA 1
```